# numpy.delete flattens my array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy

Say I do the following:

```
my_array = np.array([[1,2,3]])
my_new_array = np.delete(my_array, [])
```

The last line will convert `my_array` to:

```
my_new_array = np.array([1,2,3]) # It flattens the array one level
```

which is not what I expected.

If instead I had had:

```
my_array = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
my_new_array = np.delete(my_array, [])
```

I would get:

```
my_new_array = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
```

which is what I expect. How can I make sure a call to `np.delete(my_array, [])` does not flattens my array?

Comment: First a small warning about delete, in current numpy its a bit shaky (its not that bad mostly negative indexes don't work). Second have you had a look at the documentation? `np.delete` takes an axes argument which defaults to None, thus flattening the array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html):

> numpy.delete(arr, obj, axis=None)
>
> axis : int, optional
>
> The axis along which to delete the subarray defined by obj. If axis is None, obj is applied to the **flattened array**

Because you are not supplying anything to `axis`, it is flattening the array. You could do the following:

```
>>> print np.delete(my_array, [], axis=0)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Which seems to be the result that you want. However, it is unclear why you want to apply a transformation that gives you the same array.